# Receiving error message when running python selenium, WebDriverException error code in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

when I am trying to extract data from a website and am experimenting with code. I have downloaded chromedriver already. When I run the following code through Jupyter notebooks I receive an error:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

# Opening the connection and grabbing the page
my_url = 'https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en'
option = Options()
option.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get(my_url)
driver.maximize_window()
```

Here is the error code:

```
Error message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
     77         except TypeError:

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    799                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 800                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    801         except:

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1206                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1207                                          startupinfo)
   1208             finally:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-39e43e779b64> in <module>
----> 1 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     71             service_args=service_args,
     72             log_path=service_log_path)
---> 73         self.service.start()
     74 
     75         try:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     81                 raise WebDriverException(
     82                     "'%s' executable needs to be in PATH. %s" % (
---> 83                         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     84                 )
     85             elif err.errno == errno.EACCES:

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Please help! Any ideas on how to fix are greatly appreicated!

Answer (score 1):

The last line says it all:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

You have to download `chromedriver` from [Google](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home)

Comment: Thanks, but I already installed it and it still gives me this error.

Comment: and need to be in path

Comment: @Avatazjoe, could you explain what this means, how it is done?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: !pip install chromedriver_installer

Comment: @goalie it doesnt matter wich OS, he is using jupyter so its isolated env just run !pip for jupyternotebook

Comment: @Avatazjoe in Windows chromedriver doesn't need to be in PATH or in the venv as long as it it's in the same directory as the ipynb file.

Comment: @Avatazjoe Thanks! does it matter if I put this code through Jupyter or my windows CMD line?

Comment: as long you have chromedriver in the same directory as @goalie1998 said the diference will be the invoking command, on cmd you dont need the exclamation mark... may i forget something?

Comment: @Avatazjoe Thanks, tried running !pip install chromedrive_installer and it is taking awhile loading this cell, not sure why? Any reason it might be taking a long time to install it?

Comment: @goalie1998 Thanks! How do I find out where the ipynb files are located in my computer?

Comment: try: !pip freeze

Comment: When you run the jupyter notebook, what command do you use?

Comment: @goalie1998 I just open through Anaconda, then go to Jupyter notebooks, then open a new Python 3 file, and type of code and hit shift+ENTER to run it.

Comment: I believe if you open anaconda and type where python it should give you the location